# Trigger change on input when is changed by another input

Tags: jquery

I have two inputs A nad B and in input a i have set `onchange=$("#B").val($(this).val())`

i have set `$(B).change(function(){aler('ok');})` but nothing happend.. How this should be made ?

Answer (score 1):

Two typos :

```
$('#B').change(function(){alert('ok');});
```

Use [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) or Firebug (type F12) to see errors.

You might want to type some tests in the console, like

```
$('#B')
```

To see on what you're working.

Comment: Yes has typos, but jQuery will not trigger a fn.change() event on and input if you use fn.val() to set it. Change events is triggered automaticaly only by UI interation.

Answer (score 1):

Call change() on B without args to trigger the event on B.

```
$("#A").change(function(){
   $("#B").val($(this).val()).change();   // call change with args to trigger the change   event on B
});

$("#B").change(function() { alert("OK"); });
```

**EDIT:** You can change the behavior of $.fn.val to trigger the change event on it. But I don't really know if this change can result in a bad behavior.

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var originalVal = $.fn.val;
        $.fn.val = function () {
            if (!arguments.length)
                return originalVal.call(this);

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);

            return this.each(function () {
                var self = $(this);
                originalVal.apply(self, args);
                self.change();
            });
        };
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: It's to many things to change i'm trying to make this outside to handle change